# React Native iOS Standard and Zoomed Display

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a problem in RN iOS app. When display is standard everything is fine, but when it is Zoomed, the top bar totally messes up, users can't click on any anything in top bar. Tried *`SafeAreaView`* but did not helped the cause.

Question is there any way to find out if the display is zoomed or standard?

Comment: What do you mean with "Zoomed top bar"?

Comment: @MtgKhaJeskai sorry brother, its a typo. check updated post

Comment: But what do you meen when you say that your application is Zoomed, I cannot make zoom in my application. Maybe if you have an image inside?

Comment: I hope you are aware of zoomed and standard display in iOS. Its not in mu app, but iphone users can change phone setting to make everything zoomed/standard. When it is zoomed my app is messed

Comment: Aaah, I know what are you referring now. So, sorry I don't know what could you do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the solution for finding if the display is zoomed or standard

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'

const DEVICES = [
    'iPhone X',
    'iPhone XS',
    'iPhone XS Max',
    'iPhone XR'
]

const DEVICE_STANDARD_HEIGHTS = {
    "iPhone X": 812,
    "iPhone XS": 812,
    "iPhone XS Max": 896,
    "iPhone XR": 896,
}


const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");

const device_name = DeviceInfo.getModel();


let is_zoomed = false;

if (DEVICES.includes(device_name)) {
    if (DEVICE_STANDARD_HEIGHTS[device_name] > height) { // because when display is zoomed height is less than the standard display
        is_zoomed = true;
    }
}
```

Modify it according to your requirements :)