# React Native views are scaled up when setting iOS's Display Zoom to 'Zoomed' instead of 'Standard'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a react native app, and when we tested it on the client's iPhone the layout was broken. Then we discovered that it's because of the Display Zoom was set to 'Zoomed' on the client's phone, and now we're supposed to make it work.
I read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54251683/8118054 but it's not a viable solution right now since it requires us to re-write most of the CSS in our app, which would take a lot of time. So is there any other solution like adding a prop to every View or any other faster solution?

[With Display Zoom set to 'Zoomed'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6YUt.png)

[With Display Zoom set to 'Standard'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itgrm.jpg)

Comment: did you finally get a solution ?